# How to configure Cruise Control with CVS

Tags: build-process, cruisecontrol.net, build-automation, cvs, configuration-management

I am first time using Cruise Control for Automation of build. Please Guide me how can I configure Cruise Control with my CVS Server. I installed Cruise Control , does it require any extra plug-in. how can I write config file, Where i have to place it.

Comment: Are you using cruise control or cruise control .NET? These are two different programs...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: More pertinent instructions:

From [here](http://www.igloocoder.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/CVS%20Source%20Control%20Block.html):

**example using pserver authentication**

```
<sourcecontrol type="cvs">
   <executable>..\tools\cvs.exe</executable>
   <cvsroot>:pserver:anonymous@cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/ccnet</cvsroot>
   <module>ccnet</module>
   <workingDirectory>c:\projects\ccnet</workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

**example using ssh via putty**

```
<sourcecontrol type="cvs">
   <executable>c:\putty\cvswithplinkrsh.bat</executable>
   <cvsroot>:ext:mycvsserver:/cvsroot/myrepo</cvsroot>
   <module>mymodule</module>
   <workingDirectory>c:\fromcvs\myrepo</workingDirectory>
</sourcecontrol>
```

Loads of information here : http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+CVS

http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/configxml.html#cvs

Comment: Note that the first link is for Cruise Control .NET and the second one for Cruise Control.

Comment: I don't know the purpose of this batch."cvswithplinkrsh.bat" in first link. I don't need to use any SSH client.

Comment: Thanks Preet .it seems i have to download Putty.exe for ssh client. But i don't need to use any security. Is there any way I only enter my cvs-server id and password in config file. Cruise control directly connect me with cvs and start working.

Comment: I am still facing problem. Please have a look on my ccnet.config file

Comment: My ccnnet.config file.<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
 <!-- This is your CruiseControl.NET Server Configuration file. Add your projects below! -->

   <project name="Abs.Web.cCon.Mobile" />
 <sourcecontrol type="cvs">
    <executable>..\tools\cvs.exe</executable>
    <cvsroot>:pserver:maqsood.ahmad@cvs-server:/cvsroot/Afrah</cvsroot>
    <module>ccnet</module>
    <workingDirectory>D:\projects\Abs.Web.cCon.Mobile</workingDirectory>
 </sourcecontrol>

 </cruisecontrol>                                                         and the error message when i run ccnet.exe..

Comment: My ccnnet.config file.<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder"> <!-- This is your CruiseControl.NET Server Configuration file. Add your projects below! --> <project name="Abs.Web.cCon.Mobile" /> <sourcecontrol type="cvs"> <executable>..\tools\cvs.exe</executable> <cvsroot>:pserver:maqsood.ahmad@cvs-server:/cvsroot/Afrah</cvsroot> <module>ccnet</module> <workingDirectory>D:\projects\Abs.Web.cCon.Mobile</workingDirectory> </sourcecontrol> </cruisecontrol> and the error message when i run ccnet.exe.. –